# How to show that a limit of a function exists with a variable

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x}{\ln(5x+1)} , x>0 \\
> \frac{2x+\alpha}{x+3} , x\le 0 \\
> \end{cases}$$
>
> For which $\alpha$ there exists a limit for $f$ in $x_0=0 $ ?

I tried to go from the definition of a limit so $|f(0)-L|<\epsilon$ which leads me to $|\frac{\alpha}{3}-L|<\epsilon $ but I don't really know what to do from here...

Help please ?

**NOTE**: we can't use integration/derivation/L'hopital/Taylor's because we haven't covered those (i.e. "no calculus").

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @DavidH We can't use it. I edited the post.

Comment: can we use the expansion series of ln(1+x)

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, searching for it reveals that it has to do with Taylor's theorem so I guess not ?

Comment: Can you use the fact that when "y" is small, log(1+y) is almost equal to "y" ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici isn't that same as using the expansion and ignoring the higher order terms

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw. Yes and no ! When you teach logarithm, you can show, even graphically, that close to the origin the two curves are very close to eachother. Since I do not know what the OP has been teached up to now, I asked that, forgetting on purpose to mention Taylor. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't think we've been shown that. Is it a known "identity" ?

Comment: @GinKin. Are you allowed to compute the value of the first function for x=0.1, 0.01, 0.001 ?

Comment: @GinKin We don't know what can be considered as "known" in your case. You need something that allows you to determine $$\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}.$$ If that is done, the rest is a piece of cake. How to show that limit is $1$, that depends on what you have at your disposal.

Comment: @claude, we're not allowed calculators so I guess not. You want to calculate it to show that it goes to a number? Won't a limit be enough ?

Comment: @daniel, I think that we're suppose to do it from the definition of a limit. As I said in the note, by a "no calculus" method.

Comment: @GinKin To even be able to show that the limit exists, you must use some properties of $\ln$. We don't know what properties you officially know and are allowed to use.

Comment: @GinKin.What are you supposed to know about logarithms ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I just went through my notes, we saw in class that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ We used an e identity. does that help ?

Comment: @GinKin.This helps a lot. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first function can be written as (1/5) (5 x) / log(1 + 5 x). Since, when y is small, log(1+y)/y goes to 1, the reverse is true that is to say that y / log(1+y) goes to 1 when y goes to 0. Replace y by (5 x). So, your first function goes to (1/5). The second function goes to (a / 3) when x goes to 0. Since you want the continuity, you then have to solve (a / 3) = (1 /5) which leads to a = 3 /5.

I think we made it !

Is this clear for you now ? If not, just post. Cheers.

Comment: So basically we want to find the limit from both sides in order to find what is appropriate alpha right ?

Comment: @GinKin. Yes sir !

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @GinKin.You welcome ! It took time but we made it all together. Thanks to all of you who participated to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

set
$t = 5x$

and then solve

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\ln(5x+1)} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac15t}{\ln(t+1)}$

Comment: That helped thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expansion for ln(5x+1) and solve limit as usual . You will get  α =  3/5 .

Comment: I don't think we covered expansion yet.

Comment: You can use some standard limit like lim x->0 sin x/x , lim x->0 tan x / x and so on  similarly for lim x->0  x / ln(ax +1) = 1/a .

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you give more details on how to solve it in your answer ?

Comment: ln(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+x^5/5 +.... and for ln(1+ax) put ax instead of x and than cancel x from NUMERATOR and DENOMINATOR and put x = 0 and u will get "a" as answer .

Comment: I found that identity you used here http://www.math.sc.edu/~girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf but I still don't see how you show here the limit, much less how does finding what the ln expands to helps with finding the alpha...